# htaccess rewrite URL and remove GET parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to URL rewrite, regex and .htaccess

Here is an issue I am facing:

I have this url with GET parameter:
`www.mysite.in/alpha-beta/abc.php?id=APPLE%strike=200.00`

I want to display it like:
`www.mysite.in/alpha/beta/APPLE/200.00`

This is the code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^alpha/beta/(.*)/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))$ alpha-beta/abc.php?id=$1&strike=$2 [NC,L]
```

But I only get a blank page when I go to URL: `www.mysite.in/alpha/beta/APPLE/200.00`

When I change the htaccess rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^alpha/beta/(.*)/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))$ http://www.mysite.in/alpha-beta/abc.php?id=$1&strike=$2 [NC,L]
```

It redirects to correct page but the URL is displayed as `http://www.mysite.in/alpha-beta/abc.php?id=APPLE&strike=200.00`

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Added new information. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: You could be right. I haven;t dome any changes/ addition to rewritten URL? can you give some more information on what additional css/js should be there for the purpose of rewriting?

Comment: This one is with absolute link in htaccess: http://www.niftytrader.in/OI_TOOL/LTP/ADANIPORTS/300.00      and this is with relative link in htaccess: http://www.niftytrader.in/OI_TOOL/IV/ADANIPORTS/300.00

Comment: It is because `http://www.niftytrader.in/OI_TOOL/IV/ADANIPORTS/300.00` is unable to load your `getIV.php` via jquery and results in 404.

Comment: Do you know any way around this? iv_chart.php is fetching data from getIV.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^OI_TOOL/IV/(.*)/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+))/?$ OI_ANALYSIS_TOOL/iv_chart.php?symbol=$1&str‌​ike=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# fix path for getIV.php by redirecting it to /OI_ANALYSIS_TOOL/
RewriteRule ^OI_TOOL/.+?/(getIV\.php)$ /OI_ANALYSIS_TOOL/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working perfectly. Though It will take me a while to understand it :) Cheers

Comment: Just one more issue. The same 2 parameters are being passed to getIV.php but I think the above solution is only passing one parameter. could you suggest the changed version?

Comment: http://www.niftytrader.in/OI_TOOL/OI/ADANIPORTS/330.00 and http://www.niftytrader.in/OI_ANALYSIS_TOOL/oi_chart.php?symbol=ADANIPORTS&strike=330.00 should show same results but its not same. the first link is showing result for strike=0.00 (it seems)

Comment: That is due to your own code inside `drawChart` function that you need to fix.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I was just browsing thru this question and clicked unintentionally. How do I revert it?